# Dynamic collapse div wrong align - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using collapse for some text content. When we toggle. The div uppends to the above div in wordpress contents. Kindly check the attachment image to understand the issue further.

I tried using `<br>` but it dosent help. Also tried with `padding-top, padding-bottom` but in some situations the content are dynamic so the padding creates gaps between the divs.

[image]

If you see the above image the `What are u` content should be below but it uppends to the div above. Is there any solution other then padding?

```
<div class="collapse">
    <p class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-136" aria-expanded="true"><span class="collapse-icon"><!-- --></span> Who ru ?</p>
    <div id="-collapse-136" class="-collapse-text collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <p><span class="TextRun SCX56189914" lang="EN-GB" xml:lang="EN-GB">
<span class="NormalTextRun SCX56189914">
<a href="opt1.jpg">
<img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-57609" src="opt1-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150">
</a>Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content Top Content TopContent TopContent Top Content Top
</span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse">
    <p class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-137" aria-expanded="true"><span class="collapse-icon"><!-- --></span> What Am I</p>
    <div id="-collapse-137" class="-collapse-text collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <p><span class="TextRun SCX56189914" lang="EN-GB" xml:lang="EN-GB">
<span class="NormalTextRun SCX56189914">
<a href="opt1.jpg">
<img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-57609" src="opt1-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150">
</a>Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong
Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content WrongContent Wrong  Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong Content Wrong
</span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share your html/css

Comment: please provide code. May be it is a loop peoblem.

Comment: As its dynamic i could not able to get u the full page.. i copied the collapse part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution and it worked perfectly for my senario:

```
.collapse {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add following CSS to resolve this issue:

```
.collapse {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```